# Two characters, three meanings

Tags: riddle, knowledge

All of the following apply:

- Help!
- I'm fast
- I'm fast, hot and huge

Note: The `knowledge` needed is rather wide, so don't let it stop you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer to this is:

> the two-character string '**F1**'.

*Help!*

> The **F1** key on a computer keyboard opens the *Help* system for the active window.

*I'm fast*

> [Formula One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_One) - also known as **F1** - is a high-speed (i.e. *fast*) motor racing format.

*I'm fast, hot and huge*

> The [Rocketdyne **F-1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_F-1) was the rocket engine used to power the [Saturn V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V) rocket in the 1960s and 70s. To this day it remains 'the most powerful single combustion chamber liquid-propellant rocket engine ever developed' (Source: Wikipedia). In order for rockets using it to escape Earth's atmosphere, this engine would undeniably have been *fast*, *hot* and *huge*!
>
>  <sub>*Initial attempt for the third part (not the OP's intent):* In astronomical nomenclature, '**F1**' indicates a specific subclass of '[F-type main sequence star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-type_main-sequence_star)'. Being a star, it is definitely *fast* (travelling at speeds of hundreds of thousands of miles per hour), *hot* (with some of these burning balls of gas registering at well over a thousand degrees Celsius), and *huge* (just look at our own Sun, for example - not directly, though...).</sub>

Comment: I have a different thing in mind for the third point. It is still related to astronomy, but not THAT hot and huge...care to give another try? (also, in yes in a way stars are fast, but you wouldn't really call them fast in an everyday/layman's view, right? You'd still call mine fast :) )

Comment: Ahh...no. Maybe instead of "astronomy", I should mention "engineering". It's in between there.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Okay, I think I now realise what you're pointing towards - how about now?!

Comment: yepp! Saw a yt video about an engineer explaining stuff about the Saturn V so it served as an inspiration.